# SQL - linetotal based on grouping

Tags: sql

[enter image description here][1]I need to group the GRN and AP invoice total value based on GRN and PO document entry. I've done different ways of getting the distinct values for GRN and AP invoice value but it will come not as expected that is due to linking of one document to another document. As per the structure is no any other of relating the sequence of the documents.

I tried CTE option to achieve the same but its giving the double the value in GRN and AP totals which is not correct as per the records posted.

Group Values images has been attached.

Your help is much appreciated.

Regards,

```
DocNum  DocTotal    LineTotal   VatSum  LineTotal   VatSum  BaseLine    BaseEntry   ItemCode    LineTotal   VatSum  BaseLine    BaseEntry
199 47931.6 10150   1827    7250    1305    0   199 I001570 7250    1305    0   163
199 47931.6 10150   1827    2900    522 0   199 I001570 2900    522 0   164
199 47931.6 19350   3483    19350   3483    1   199 I001571 8600    1548    0   165
199 47931.6 19350   3483    19350   3483    1   199 I001571 10750   1935    0   165
199 47931.6 11120   2001.6  5560    1000.8  2   199 I001572 2780    500.4   0   166
199 47931.6 11120   2001.6  5560    1000.8  2   199 I001572 2780    500.4   0   166
199 47931.6 11120   2001.6  5560    1000.8  2   199 I001572 5560    1000.8  0   167

requirement                                         
        GRN Line total  GRN vat sum         AP line total                   
        40620   7311.6          40620                   
        47931.6             47931.6                 
Final value                                         
    47931.6                                     
    47931.6                                     
    47931.6
```

-- unable add the image and i don't know how to explain easily. please refer the values above in order to better understand.

Regards,

Comment: Images is not displayed here. It would be good if you can provide the table schema and sample records instead of image

Comment: Can you add some samples of input data and desired output?

Comment: if you share your mail id i ll share the excel sheet for better understanding.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask, especially https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: sql db regards,